# Visual Installer Project - can't run app after instalation without admin right

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I'm trying to add Visual installer project (setup ) to my project and I have a little troubels with this. I'm using Visual Studio 2017. After installation my application don't open until i start app with admin rights, it's need only once, next running don't need admin permissions and everything works ok.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please give us detailed information abour your issue maybe put a link to minimal-complete-verifiable copy of your project if you think your project is the problem.

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036732/unauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-is-denied  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587622/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-while-running-exe-under-program-files